# Remove Material UI icon margin

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Does anyone know how to remove the margin from material UI icons!? I want for mobile to remove that margin, which is margin-left: -4px and margin-right: 8px  ? Is there anyway to override it with classes?
The code below is not working:

```
personIcon: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    fontSize: "27px !important",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      margin: "0px !important",
    },
  },
```

In addition I want to override it only for the current component. ;]
[image]

Comment: I don't see a margin on a default icon, e.g. `@material-ui/icons/Person`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just added a screenshot

Comment: Ah, it's part of a `Button` component, that's kinda crucial information :wink:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the `startIcon` customization point, as [documented here](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#css).

In my example I just used `SvgIcon` so I don't have to fiddle around with looking for the icons module. You can import `Person` from `@material-ui/icons/person`

```js
const { Button, makeStyles, SvgIcon, createMuiTheme } = MaterialUI;

const theme = createMuiTheme();
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  icon: {
    '&& > svg': {
      fontSize: 27,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
      margin: 0,
    },
  },
}));

const NoMargin = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Button
      classes={{ startIcon: classes.icon }}
      startIcon={
        <SvgIcon>
          <path d="M12 12c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4s-1.79-4-4-4-4 1.79-4 4 1.79 4 4 4zm0 2c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v2h16v-2c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z" />
        </SvgIcon>
      }
    >
      click me
    </Button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<NoMargin />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
personIcon: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    fontSize: "27px !important",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      "& > *": {
         margin: 0,
       },
    },
},
```